# how can i fire a workflow from Sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have a requirement.
Which is i would like to know when a user clicks on an item
So what i'm thinking of doing is to have a checkbox on the page(I would be buiding a custom webpart for this neither in Sharepoint Designer or in Object model)
When the user click the checkbox i want to update another list with the users username and ID of the item.
I need this as i would have to report who hasn't read the item.
Can i attach this checkbox to a workflow?

** Please feel free to advice if there are any other approach to tackle this

Comment: Your question looks very unclear, I think you should edit to explain it properly

Comment: Sorry it wasn't well explained.
The question is how can i fire a workflow using a check box in sharepoint designer.
Thanks in advance